# Can't set focus on TextBox inside detailsview

Tags: asp.net

The `DetailsView.FindControl("TextBox1")` returns me the correct textbox where I want to set focus but setting focus using any of the following ways does not work

1. (TextBox)DetailsView.FindControl("TextBox1").Focus()
2. Page.SetFocus("TextBox1");
3. Got the Id of this textbox by Viewing page source and SetFocus on that.
4. Made sure that DetailsView is in Edit/Insert mode before focus is set.

None of the above has worked, I am stuck.

Note - Its works if DetailsView is inside Panel but not working where it is inside tabpanel

Comment: Is you DetailsView inside of UpdatePanel by any chance?

Comment: Hi Yurih, Thanks for responding. Its not inside UpdatePanel. It is inside ajaxTollkit's TabPanel.

Comment: what is detailsView exactly represent? a specific row ?

Comment: ahmed - Didn't get your question. For me it simple is a one column grid you can say and I want to set focus on the first cell of the first row of this column which is a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
(TextBox)DetailsView.FindControl("TextBox1").Focus();
```

Try

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "SetFocus", "document.getElementById('" + (TextBox)DetailsView.FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```

*UPDATE*

Here's another approach that uses ScriptManager:

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)DetailsView.FindControl("TextBox1");
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).SetFocus(textBox);
```

Comment: Since the TextBox is inside DetailsView I can't access it directly on the code behind. I have to use FindContol on DetailsView to get access to it. This part is complaing due to that.

Comment: So I tried this 
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "SetFocus", "document.getElementById('" +DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID + "').focus();", true);
I get following error message
Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled or a control that does not receive focus.

Comment: I think you found the root of the problem. Is it capable of receiving focus?

Comment: It is a Asp.Net TextBox control. I can set focus anywhere on these textboxes except inside the DetailsView.

Comment: So it is not disabled or invisible?

Comment: no, I can change text by finding the control on DEtailsView and setting text, but not focus.

Comment: "by finding the control on DEtailsView and setting text" - in server-side code only or by manually clicking on it and typing text as well?

Comment: By finding it on DEtailsView and setting text on server side code and also by typing

Comment: Updated my answer with another approach. Can u give it a try?

Comment: Didn't work :(, I have tried it on both PageLoad as well as OnModeChanging for DetailsView